# How can I write a comma between each value of a vector?

Tags: r

I would like to export a vector to a file with a comma between each value. I've tried to use `paste` with `sep = ","` but it does not work. Does anyone know why?

```
> x <- rnorm(10)
> paste(x, sep = ",")
[1] "-1.08574649988891"  "2.9580381152357"    "-0.549880906960338" "1.79794352588269"   "-1.06316832291584"  "-1.56636513327118"  "0.363867572492577" 
[8] "-0.644707355221403" "0.617827074223129"  "-1.50892267338431"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `sep` separates objects; `collapse` separates elements.

```
> paste(letters[1:3], 1:3, sep=",", collapse="|")
[1] "a,1|b,2|c,3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> write.table(matrix(1:10, 1), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

or this:

```
> cat(1:10, sep = ","); cat("\n")
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Also note that both `write.table` and `cat` support `file=` and `append=` arguments.